# HornetQ : Timeout durable subscriptions where client not connected for X amount of time

Tags: jms, hornetq

We have recently started using hornetq on a project and we use durable subscriptions to topics. However we have no control over the subscribers. What we would like to do is timeout the durable subscriptions if the client hasn't connected in the last 24 hours. There are a couple reasons for wanting to do this. The main reason is that the client id could change or the connecting client might just disappear.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems a nice feature to have. You should open a feature request.

Meanwhile you could use management API to discover the queues you have, and the number of consumers on them. At this point you would have to control such thing outside of hornetq.

We would accept contributions if someone implemented the feature, and we could collaborate on the process.